# Windows 7 displaying Shift/Alt/Control/Meta balloon dialog

Tags: windows-7, accessibility

After a reboot today, suddenly Windows 7 is showing a little balloon dialog almost in the center of my display every time I hold down shift, control, alt, or the windows key. You can see it in the screenshot below.

I can only guess that this is some sort of accessibility feature, but I haven't been able to find anything related to this in the Ease of Access Center.

How do I disable this?  I have tried a Google search, but I don't even know what search terms to use so I get an overwhelming number of results not related to this issue.

Additional information:  I run a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard, plus a VisTablet PenPad writing tablet. The driver for the tablet has recently been updated.

[image: Screenshot]